# Fetching feed data using facebook graph API using FB Android SDK failing?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was making an attempt to the user's feed data using the `Facebook Android SDK` . The permissions are given as I are seen with the logs , but the SDK later shows a pop-up saying that the permission is denied to access feed data . The log obtained is as under :

```
Client Request = [user_posts ]    Bundle is Bundle[{access_token=yyy,
expires_in=5175894, denied_scopes=manage_notifications,publish_actions, e2e={"init":1429880683556},
granted_scopes=public_profile,user_posts, signed_request=xx.xx}]
```

Comment: Are you using the same user as the app creation or logging in with another user ? If its the latter case have you gotten your permissions reviewed from facebook?

Comment: Hi @Dilum , I have tried both the cases but to no avail . And in any case I haven't verified any permissions with facebook .